# Open an app windowless

Tags: macos, automation, javascript-automation

Can we launch apps hidden (i.e. without windows, the same effect we get on <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) via JavaScript for Automation (JXA)?

The best I could achieve so far is:

```
const app = Application('AppName')
if (!app.running()) app.windows().forEach(window => window.visible = false)
```

Which gives unreliable results. In Firefox it mostly works; in iTerm it never works; and in other apps it might work but there’s a “flash” of the window opening before hiding.

Solutions that do not use JXA aren’t acceptable, because this needs to fit into larger scripts. Using the Objective-C bridge is acceptable.

Comment: which app are you scripting? it's best to focus on one app, instead of trying to get a global answer since, as you said, multiple apps behave differently.

Comment: @ankii I’m looking for a general solution, not an answer that works on a single app. Multiple apps behave differently *with the given solution*, but they don’t work differently with `.activate()`, for example. Either there’s a standard solution or there is not.